# Android Activity change

Tags: android

I have Tow Activities A and B. when i Switch between A to B i need animation for Activity B.When i pressesd back button in activity B the Activity B exit with Animation.

Please Answer to this question.

Hope your Qucik Response.

Comment: double post with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563723/adding-animation-in-activity-change-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing finish() while calling B Activity from A activity

```
        Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(aActivity.this,bActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_exit,R.anim.disapear);
```