# Adding Animation in Activity Change in android

Tags: android

I have two Activities A and B . When i swithc between activity A to B the Activity b comes with 3d transition animation.when i press a back button in Activity B the Activity B exits with Animation.

Please Answer.

Hope Your Quick Response.

Comment: There's no question in your post. Normally questions end in questions marks

Answer (score 0):

```
  Activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Use this code snippet in your activity onCreate() Method.You can achieve the transition effect.